# Program crashes under weird condition

Tags: assembly, x86

I am new to assembly and I have a weird bug. I use the 286 and TASM assembler. I emulate on dosbox my program. My program simply ask users to imput a string and it will then output the same string. Here is my whole code:

```
.286
.model huge
.stack 300h

.CODE
start:


lea bx, x
push bx
call gets   ; Read the string
lea bx, x
push bx
call puts   ; Output the string

jmp terminate   ; End it

; ---------- char getche(void) ----------

getche:
; Reads a character from keyboard and output into dl register

push ax     ; push stacks we use

mov ah, 1h  ; get character and echo
int 21h
mov dl, al  ; output the character into dl

pop ax      ; pop  the stacks

ret     ; return

; ---------- end of function ----------

; ---------- void putch(char c) ----------

putch:
; Print character into screen

push ax     ;Push the stacks we use
push bx
push dx
push bp

mov bp, sp  ; Load the character
mov bx, [bp+10]

mov dl, [bx]    ; store the argument into dx
mov ah, 2h  ; print the character
int 21h

pop bp      ; Pop all the stacks we used
pop dx
pop bx
pop ax

ret 2       ; return

; ---------- end of function ----------

; ---------- void puts(char *p) ----------

puts:
; Prints string to the console

push bp     ; Push the stacks
push bx
push cx

mov cl, 0   ; The null character
mov bp, sp

mov bx, [bp+8]  ; Load the adress of beginning of the string

.pts_loop:
cmp [bx], cl
jz .pts_exit    ; Jump if it is the null character

push bx
call putch  ; Print the character
inc bx
jmp .pts_loop

.pts_exit:
pop cx      ; Pop the stacks
pop bx
pop bp

ret 2

; ---------- end of function ----------

; ---------- void gets(char *p) ----------

gets:
; Reads a string from keyboard

push bp ; Push stacks
push bx
push cx

mov bp, sp ; Load the address
mov bx, [bp+8]
mov cl, 13

.gts_loop:
call getche
mov [bx], dl
inc bx
cmp dl, cl ; Check if it is the 'Enter' key
jnz SHORT .gts_loop

mov [bx], 0 ; Add the null

pop cx      ; Pop stacks
pop bx
pop bp

ret 2


; ---------- end of function ----------

terminate:
mov ah, 4ch     ; terminate the program
mov al, 00
int 21h

.DATA

x db "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" ; Doesn't matter what's inside

END start
```

If the length of my string is <= 10. It will terminate with no problem. However if it is > 10 then it crashes. I used debug and I notice during the execution everything runs normally until it goes to the termination. When I do the interrupt it jumps somehwere where there are all 0's and it runs forever... I guess my string might overwrite some important data. I tried to move the .DATA from beginning of my code to the end but it doesn't help much. Any suggestion?

EDIT: I change `mov cl, 13` to `mov cl, 0`. I increased the stack to 200h and even 300h but still same problem.

Comment: When I declared my x variable, the length is greater than 20 but my code crashes once I put 11 characters. I don't see how it can be overflow.

Comment: Confusing comment: `mov cl, 13 ; The null character`. Since you check for this 'null' elsewhere, it may even be the source of your troubles.

Comment: I think Jongware has it: When you print, you are looking for a chr(13) end marker, but you actually stored chr(0) when you read the string.

Comment: I changed it but it's the same error. Char(13) is the 'Enter' and when you input a string from user it will register the 'Enter' so the mistake is not fatal.

Comment: putch: ret "2" is wrong?

Comment: No it's good as I am pushing bx before I call putch so I pop 2 at the end.

Comment: Maybe we get "far" calls, if we use model huge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize `DS`:

```
...
.CODE
start:
mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax
...
```

For a MS-DOS program you have to initialize DS **always**!

I tested it and now your code works for me.

BTW:

If there is no special reason for `.model huge`, avoid it! Use `.model small`.

Change

```
mov [bx], 0 ; Add the null ; *Warning* Argument needs type override
```

to

```
mov byte ptr [bx], 0 ; Add the null
```

Comment: Yes it works! Thank you so much. My teacher never talked about initializing DS.

Answer (score 1):

You never setup DS/ES.

```
mov ax,.DATA  ; <-- Syntax used depends on assembler used!!!
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
```

Alternatively completly remove the *.DATA* directive. This will place the string *x* in the *.CODE* section so this time setup DS/ES with code like

```
start:
 mov ax,cs
 mov ds,ax
 mov es,ax
```

The fact that problems first start at DOS function 4Ch when more than 10 characters were processed stems from the fact that at offset 10 within the ProgramSegmentPrefix DOS keeps some very important interrupt vectors. These were overwritten by not initializing DS. When an EXE starts the DS register points to the PSP.

Comment: On the line below **start:**

Comment: That's what I though too. After the 10th character it overwrite important code sections. It solved by mov ax, @DATA. Thank you for the help.